# Is STL vector a better version of realloc?

Tags: c++, stl, vector, realloc

In C++, I believe, a better way of dealing with reallocation is to use a STL vectors, as it guarantees the contiguous storage locations.

I have couple question to understand the difference:

1. Is there any scenario in which I need to prefer [realloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/realloc) over vector ?
2. Is there anything else ( apart from vector ) which is equivalent to [realloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/realloc) in C++?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is only `vector`, which is guaranteed to have contiguous memory. Not the others.

`realloc` is a C memory management function. It's use is not encouraged in C++ code. Here's Stroustrup telling you why: [Why doesn't C++ have an equivalent to realloc()?](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#renew)

> However, realloc() is only guaranteed to work on arrays allocated by malloc() (and similar functions) containing objects without user-defined copy constructors. Also, please remember that contrary to naive expectations, realloc() occasionally does copy its argument array.

Comment: realloc won't work with anything but POD types, as it does not know about constructors/destructors.

Comment: vector's also have the advantage over malloc's memory in that they will be deleted when they go out of scope, thus decreasing memory leaks when exceptions are thrown, when you forget to free() the memory, etc.

Comment: @GiovanniFunchal Fixed the link.

Answer (score 11):

The set of C functions (malloc, calloc, realloc, free) are raw memory operations. They will create/modify/release a given buffer in memory, but the memory will have no type and no constructors will be called.

C++ does not have an equivalent of *realloc*, but only typesafe equivalents to malloc/free through the use of *new/new[]* and *delete/delete[]*. The C++ versions will both acquire the memory from the system *and* initialize it by calling the appropriate constructors. Using *delete* will call the destructors of the objects and then release the memory. C and C++ versions are not compatible, if you acquire memory with *malloc* (even if you call the inplace constructor on the received memory) you cannot release it with *delete/delete[]* as it is undefined behavior.

Using *realloc* in C++ might be unsafe, as it will bitwise copy the objects from one memory area to the next. Sometimes your objects will not deal properly with memory moves (say that your object has both an attribute and a reference to it, after bitwise moving it the reference will be pointing to the old position rather than the real attribute). Inside *vector*, whenever the memory needs to grow, a new memory area is acquired with *new[]* and then all objects are copied to (or copy constructed in) the new positions using the appropriate C++ operations before deleting the old elements.

Whenever *vector* grows in size (reserved size, not used size) it will create a complete new memory area and *move* all the objects. On the other hand, realloc will only move the memory block to another position if there is not enough contiguous space after the pointer to just *grow* it. *Vectors* do not decrease size. Never. When you clear the elements, the reserved memory is still held.

Finally, there is a higher level of abstraction in *vector* than in realloc even for POD types (that are safe to be moved with C-like constructs). The equivalent to *vector* would be a structure that holds the pointer to the memory buffer, a used elements count and a reserved (buffer size) and the set of functions that deal with acquiring more memory as needed and updating the indexes with each operation.

Comment: Vectors do not decrease size, except when calling v.shrink_to_fit(), which is new in C++11. Note that an implementation can choose to ignore the call.

Comment: @MaHuJa: `std::vector<T>(myVector).swap( myVector );` will in all implementations I know (not mandated) shrink the vector to the appropriate size.

Answer (score 8):

Contiguous memory is also guaranteed by realloc so that's not a reason not to use it.

However, I would prefer to use a vector in C++ since it's at a higher level of abstraction, hence it makes the code easier to write.

The only possible reason I can think for using realloc (over vector) for an array-type scenario, is raw speed. It *may* be faster. And I stress the word "may" - *measure, don't guess!*

However, you have to handle your own reallocations, which is more work. I'd rather have code that runs a little slower (assuming it still runs fast enough, of course), if I can deliver it and get paid quicker.

Answer (score 5):

One of the main benefits of std::vector is that when it reallocates itself internally from naturally growing, it chooses a size that is 2x larger than the current size (usually - but always a constant multiplier). This means that push_back's have amortized O(1) cost.

Realloc will give you finer control over how you allocate memory, but with great power comes great responsibility. If you all you are doing is the equivalent of push_back, and you realloc each time you add an element, that is *potentially* an O(N) operation on each addition to the array.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's only a vector.

I haven't seen anyone who would suggest using realloc in C++.